# How to convert PKCS12 keys in a way that MD5 isn't used?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, security, certificate, openssl

I received a PFX file from a company in order to use their VPN. For openfortivpn I needed two PEM files to pass with `--user-cert=cert.pem --user-key=key.pem`, so I used `openssl pkcs12 -in REDACTED.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem -nodes` and `openssl pkcs12 -in REDACTED.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem` to extract them. And they worked on my VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu 22.10. Then I sent my laptop to have the SSD replaced (sold by mistake with one smaller than advertised), when it came back I set up a VM, this time with Ubuntu 22.04 (turned out to be necessary), and it doesn't work.

The command is `sudo openfortivpn REDACTED:11443 -u REDACTED -p REDACTED --trusted-cert REDACTED --user-cert=~/dev/cert.pem --user-key=~/dev/key.pem`. Its output:

```
WARN:   You should not pass the password on the command line. Type it interactively or use a configuration file instead.
ERROR:  SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file: error:0A080002:SSL routines::system lib
INFO:   Closed connection to gateway.
ERROR:  SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file: error:0A080002:SSL routines::system lib
INFO:   Could not log out.
```

Changing the security level in `openssl.cfn` to 1 or even 0, as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level) and corroborated with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218876/how-to-fix-ssl-issue-ssl-ctx-use-certificate-ca-md-too-weak-on-python-zeep), doesn't help. I suppose it's the server's side where it should be done, but that's unavailable to me.

Am I right in assuming that the most likely cause is that they changed in the meantime the default security level of OpenSSL on the server? And not e.g. my different (older) version of Ubuntu now?

How can I resolve this problem?

It seems to me that, since I have both the private and public key in the PFX file, I should be able to generate keys in any format I want, including PEM files which wouldn't (as they are by default, at least when this PFX file is given as input) use MD5, thus satisfying the elevated security requirements. If that's a correct approach, what are the commands needed?

Comment: Where is MD5 used in a PEM file?

Comment: 0A080002 means _OS_ error 2, which is ENOENT i.e. named file does not exist. Are you sure this openfortivpn supports tilde syntax like that? Did you try the actual directory path instead? PEM privatekey files created by `openssl pkcs12` haven't used MD5 since 2010, more than a decade before either of your Ubuntu releases, plus that error code has nothing to do with encryption at all much less MD5.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, indeed, that was the issue, it works when I replace the `~`s with `/home/km`. What a pernicious trap! Thanks for your help. If you'd like me to accept it as the answer, I'd be glad to, just post it as such.

Comment: @garethTheRed, apparently nowhere after all, I was led to erroneously believe so by reading the linked answers.